# Not getting proper result in Model Training while using Azure Machine Learning Studio with Two Class Bayes Point Machine Algorithm

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

We are using **Azure Machine Learning Studio** for building Trained Model and for that we have used **Two Class Bayes Point Machine Algorithm**.
For sample data , we have imported .CSV file that contains columns such as: **Tweets and Label**.

After deploying the web service, we got improper output.
We want our algorithm to predict the result of Label as 0 or 1 on the basis of different types tweets, that are already stored in the dataset.

While testing it with the tweets that are there in the dataset, it gives proper result, but the problem occurs while testing it with other tweets(that are not there in the dataset).

You can view our experiment over here:
 [Experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqB9z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to do a binary classification based on the textual data on tweets? If so you should try doing feature hashing before doing the classification.

Comment: Hello @Haritha: Thanks  for your response. Also I tried  using hashing feature, but not getting result as we have expected.

Comment: Actually we want to test that tweets also which are not there in the .CSV file.
Can you plz suggest, how can we do that?

Comment: Refer this text classification in Cortana Intelligence Gallery.

https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Text-Classification-Step-1-of-5-data-preparation-3

It would be great if can publish your AzureML experiment privately and share the link here. Can figure out how to solve the problem then.

Comment: Yaa.. We have published our AzureML experiment and the link is below:

Comment: We want to achieve our deadline in this week only, so I request you to plz respond me asap.

Comment: Plz refer this link: https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Experiment-created-on-12-21-2016-2

Comment: Also just FYI, though we have used both the algorithms ,we have deployed our experiment using **Two Class Bayes Point Machine Algorithm** only.

Comment: How the label is determined based on the text? Is that a sentiment analysis or what?

Comment: Actually label is determined on the basis of positive or negative tweets.

Comment: Also whether the tweet is actionable or non-actionable.

Comment: https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Experiment-created-on-12-21-2016-Solution-1

Here I've modified your experiment with adding some R scripts. the accuracy of the model is close to 0.926 which seems good. Hope you can continue forward with this.

Comment: Thanx for your effort. But while testing with your experiment we got this error:
 Execute R Script Piped (RPackage) : The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: Also, can you plz tell me , which **Train Model** have you selected while deploying the Web Service?

Comment: Check whether you are running CRAN R 3.1.0.
I would suggest to use Two-class Bayes Point machine for deploying the web service.

Comment: Yup I tried with both the options [Microsoft R Open 3.2.2 ,CRAN 3.1.0], but getting the same error.

Comment: Other thing I just want to confirm here is that, is there any major difference if we execute it using Request-Response or BES?

Comment: Can you plz respond me asap. Your help will be strongly appreciated

Comment: One more thing to ask. Have you tried to Test this experiment after Deploying the Web Service? Coz, I am facing problem in that, particularly with Resquest-Response approach.

Comment: Please note that stackoverflow is not a freelancer site that the users are time bounded to give an answer. So ASAP won't be ethical here. 
To deploy as a web service first you should save the trained model and integrate that into another experiment(Normally save as function is used for that)

Comment: The error you are getting is with the input. Make sure to add the input as "Enter data manually" function when you deploying the web service.

Comment: Yup I have tried saving the trained model and integrated that into another experiment, but sorry I am not getting what you have mentioned in last comment " Make sure to add the input as "Enter data manually" function when you deploying the web service". Can you plz elaborate?